# Remove elements from array with another array containing duplicates javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays, I want to delete the elements from first array with the second ones just once conserving the other duplicates that might be:

```
array1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2];
array2 = [1,1,2];

//resultingArray = [1,1,2,2,2];
```

It seems that all the answers I got are about removing duplicates while searching for this..

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with `filter`, but it only seems to filter all the entries

```
resultingArray = array1.filter(function(el){
   return array2.indexOf(el) === -1;
});

//resultingArray = [];
```

Another way that I could think of is removing each one of the array elements one by one like this

```
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
   if ( arr[i] === Number) {
     arr.splice(i, 1);
     i = arr.length;
};
```

But it doesn't seem to be a great way to do this?

And again the difference between those arrays will remove all the duplicated elements

Would appreciate to know the best method for this or directions to a duplicated posts that i couldn't find!!

Comment: should be `array2.indexOf(el)` not `array2.indexOf(i, el)` though it's very heard to understand that first sentence.

Comment: You are right anyway my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can loop through `array2` removing the first matching item matching the current value in `array1`. Something like this:

```js
let array1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2];
let array2 = [1,1,2];

array2.forEach(i => array1.splice(array1.indexOf(i), 1));

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Yeas!! I see, referencing the index to the splice was so simple that I couldn't see it!! Thank you Rory!

Comment: Note that the answer removes the last element from `array1` for each element of `array2` that can't be found in `array1`.